# why isn't vs code working after downloading all necessary extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

my text editor (vs code ) is not working , after writing a simple c program , it throws problem like

```
cc : The term 'gcc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,        
verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:61
+ ...  "c:\Users\HP\HTML .one\.vscode\css\hello.c\" ; if ($?) { gcc hello.c ...
+                                                               ~~~

+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gcc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

even after downloading all the necessary extension in my text editor (vs code).

Comment: Maybe you don't have gcc... I don't use vs code as C IDE so I'm not sure, but you probably should install gcc outside of vs code.

Comment: This is visual c not a c question so swapping the tags out.

Comment: i just follow the tutorial from yt and i did the same ,stilll it is not working

Comment: what it `yt`? Read the VSC docs about C++

Comment: why do you write your stuff inside the `.vscode` directory, why ius there a space in the directory name `HTML .one`, C stuff in a HTML proect?

Comment: yt = youtube and the HTML .one is a folder, in which , i created a c file , actually i don't know what to put in the question as to clarify my question so i just copy paste whole terminal in my question and it is my first time using stack over flow so , i much generally don't know that how to put question , so that's  why i copy paste my whole terminal .

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the c compiler, gcc, was not found in your path. Either install it or if you already did update your search path so your IDE can find it.